# Angular2: How can a child component consistently listen to an input from the parent component after onInit

Tags: angular, components, listener, parent-child

I am trying to implement an error message component within another parent component. In the child (error msg) component, it has an input attribute, which the parent component will be passing the error msg to the child cmp. I can't seem to have the child component consistently listening to the input field, as the child component only renders once. Can anyone give me some insight on how I can solve this?

Child Component

```
export class ErrorMessage implements OnInit {
    @Input() errorType: string;

    errorMessage;
    messages = {
    apiError: 'There is an error with your request. Please try again.',
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errorMessage = this.messages[this.errorType];
    }
}
```

Parent Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    template: '<error-message *ngIf="errorType" [errorType]="errorType"></error-message>'
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    errorType: string;

    throwingErrorFn(){
        this.errorType = 'apiError';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make `errorType` a setter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) in the child component:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log(this.errorType);
}
```

which should capture each change done to `errorType` in parent.

> `ngOnChanges` is called before `ngOnInit` and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.